# I have two formulas for calculating 'cosine similarity', what's the difference?

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis, cosine-similarity, recommendation-engine

I am doing a project about cosine similarity on movie dataset, I'm confused about the formula for calculating cosine similarity.

[image]

But I searched online, some articles show that the denominator is something like : sqrt(A1^2+B1^2) * sqrt(A2^2+B2^2) * ... * sqrt(Ai^2+Bi^2)

I'm confused, what's the difference? Which one is correct or they both are correct?

Comment: Can you give an example of "some articles"?

Comment: @xdurch0 https://medium.com/@bkexcel2014/building-movie-recommender-systems-using-cosine-similarity-in-python-eff2d4e60d24 Hi, this one, for the second example, the result is 0.792, and I tried his Python code, it gives me a result of 0.208

Comment: This is because pairwise_distances reports 1-cos(theta), you can see that both add to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one on your image is correct. In two dimensions, it is derived from the [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)
which relates the length of one side of a triangle to the length of the other two sides, and the angle opposite c, theta:

`c^2==a^2+b^2-2*b*c(cos(theta))`

You can prove this in many ways, and a good verification is to know that when `cos(gamma)==0` (side a and b are orthogonal), you get the Pythagorean Theorem.
To get the formula on the image, you have to translate it into analytical geometry (vectors)

`norm(A-B)^2==norm(A)^2+norm(B)^2−2*norm(A)*norm(B)*cos(theta)`

and by using that norm(A-B)^2 is by definition (A-B)*(A-B) and expanding
we get

`norm(A-B)^2 ==norm(A)^2+norm(B)^2-2*A*B`

So equating both expressions, and doing cancellations, yields

`norm(A)*norm(B)*cos(theta) = A*B`

which is the  (rearranged) formula on your definition (and the `norm(v) = sqrt(v*v)`).  For n dimensions you can show this works because rotating the euclidean space preserves norm and inner product, and because the 2D plane spanned by the vectors is precisely just a rotation of the xy plane.

A good sanity check is, again that orthogonality yields a cosine of 0, and that the cosine is between 0 and 1 (this [is the Cauchy Schwarz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality))

**Update:**
In the examples mentioned on your comment, you can see the results from the blog by running

```py
import sklearn.metrics.pairwise as pw
print(pw.cosine_similarity([[4,3]],[[5,5]]))
print(pw.cosine_similarity([[4,3,5]],[[5,5,1]]))
```

note that if you run:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
print(pairwise_distances([[4,3,5]],[[5,5,1]],metric='cosine'))
```

You get 0.208 instead of 0.792, this is because  pairwise_distance using the
cosine metric is given as `1-cos(theta)` (see that `0.208 + 0.792` is  1). You do this transformation because when you talk about distances, you want the distance from a point to itself to be 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so for the examples in Part 1 here (https://medium.com/@bkexcel2014/building-movie-recommender-systems-using-cosine-similarity-in-python-eff2d4e60d24), it should be 0.937 and 0.210 right?

Comment: See my updated answer, I've attached the relevant (correct) code here. I don't get the numbers (0.937,0.210) at all, I don't know how you are getting them, could you update your question showing the code you are using to get those results?

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, very helpful, problem solved.